# execvp - does argv[] have to be on heap?

Tags: c, linux, process, exec, heap-memory

I'm trying to write a function that takes a file's path and arguments and executes the file.

I know that I'm supposed to add the file's path to the beginning of the argv array before calling execvp().
I saw this solution to my problem but I don't understand why they allocate memory on the heap for newArgv:

```
int executeProgram(char *filepath, char *argv[]) {

int pid = fork();
if (!pid) {

    int num = 0;
    char **newArgv;

    while (argv[num++] != NULL);
    newArgv = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (1 + num));
    newArgv[0] = filepath;
    memcpy(&newArgv[1], argv, sizeof(char*) * num);
    execvp(newArgv[0], newArgv);
    }
    ...
}
```

Do I have to allocate memory for this newArgv on the heap using malloc or can I just save it on the stack like this?:

```
char *newArgv[num + 1];

*newArgv[0] = filepath;
for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    *newArgv[i+1] = *argv[i];
}
execvp(file_path, newArgv);
```

Comment: When reading the documentation, the only constraint on the array seems to be the value of `argv[0]` and and `argv[argc]`. So I daresay the new array can be allocated anywhere, since the call to `execvp` is supposed to  replace the running process's memory space regardless.

Comment: @Numb3rs, I think both implementations are correct.

Comment: Both snippets miss to `NULL`-terminate the `char*` array passed to `execvp()`.

Comment: Also in the 2nd snippt the de-reference operators here `*newArgv[0] =  ....` and here `*newArgv[i+1] = *argv[i];` are wrong.

Comment: Also^2 there is no need to cast to/from `void`-pointer in C.

Comment: @alk would you mind telling me what's wrong about the de-reference operators? I'm new to C.

Comment: This `*newArgv[i+1] = *argv[i];` copies a `char`. What you want is to copy a `char*` by doing `newArgv[i+1] = argv[i];`.

Comment: @alk but with the for-loop, I'm copying every character in the string, right? Might be a bit easier to do it your way but shouldn't that still work?